# Closing() with CancelEventArgs versus Form_Closing with FormClosingEventArgs

Tags: c#, performance, event-handling, formclosing

We are currently upgrading and remodularizing our code as we transfer from 32 to 64 bit system. In due process, one of our goals is to change from an Init() function where things were added as such example.

```
this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.Form_Closing);
```

I'd like Windows events to handle these sorts of things. So I went to the Form_Closing event in the Windows Form Events and [without surprise] saw that this was not the form_closing event. My question to this is, is there any difference between what is actually going on with CancelEventArgs vs FormClosingArgs, or are these two pieces of code literally doing the same thing with one being a Component of System and one being the result of a Windows Event handling what it does best? I'm just sort of diving and indulging myself into this new project as an intern. Is it possible to just replace the CancelEventArgs with the FormClosing one without any loss of data or issues?

**Code 1: CancelArgs**

```
 private void Form_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // If the user hit Cancel, just close the form.
        if (this.DialogResult == DialogResult.Ignore)
            return;

        if (this.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // If the address is not dirty, just cancel out of
            // the form.
            if (!this._editedObject.IsDirty)
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                return;
            }

            // Save changes.  If save fails, don't close the form.
            try
            {
                SaveChanges();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowException se = new ShowException();
                se.ShowDialog(ex, _errorObject);
                _errorObject = null;
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }
```

**Form_Closing -- Preferred Route**

```
private void ScheduleItemDetail_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        // If the user hit Cancel, just close the form.
        if (this.DialogResult == DialogResult.Ignore)
            return;

        if (this.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // If the address is not dirty, just cancel out of
            // the form.
            if (!this._editedObject.IsDirty)
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                return;
            }

            // Save changes.  If save fails, don't close the form.
            try
            {
                SaveChanges();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowException se = new ShowException();
                se.ShowDialog(ex, _errorObject);
                _errorObject = null;
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get the [CloseReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason(v=vs.110).aspx) property with the CancelEventArgs class, which is the only difference, since FormClosingEventArgs inherits from the CancelEventArgs class.  The FormClosingEventArgs was introduced in .Net 2.0.

Alternatively, instead of using the event, you could just override the OnFormClosing method, too.

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
  // your code
  base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```

Comment: With this OnFormClosing override method, to "use" it, would it be best to still += new Event() in my InitializeComponent() or where exactly would the call be? Still in my old Init() except I'd be replacing

this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.Form_Closing);

with...... this.OnFormClosing += new .....(this.Form_OnFormClosing);

Comment: @WhyCry You don't subscribe to it.  You just use it as I wrote it above.  If you start typing the word override, intellisense should show you a list of methods that you can override, including all of the methods that begin with the word "On".

Comment: @WhyCry I don't see any Init() method in your post, but if you use the override, you don't need to use the `+= new event...` for that method.  Just move your code into the override.

Comment: All the Init() method does is the line I posted in my question. This.closing+= etc. Thank you very much for the suggestion, Does OnFormClosing override handle the CloseReason? I'll do some research on it, but it does seem to be the ideal alternative.

Comment: @WhyCry It has the same parameters: FormClosingEventArgs, so the `e` variable will have the CloseReason property.  It's important to keep the `base.OnFormClosing(e);` call when overriding the method.